MongoDB Community Won't Connect
I'm on an M1 MacBook Air and suddenly MongoDB Compass and my Node backend can't connect to the database. MongoDB is installed with Homebrew and I updated everything.
In MongoDB Compass I get this error:
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017, connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
There was a problem connecting to localhost:27017

In the terminal I get this error when running brew services list:
Name              Status      User   File
mongodb-community error  3584 < me > ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

I noticed that homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist doesn't exist. Is it possible that it exists somewhere else?
I tried running sudo brew services start mongodb-community@8.0, and I get a different error code (15872).
The last 3 errors in the mongod log are here:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-03T14:01:59.805-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-03T14:01:59.805-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/asio/asio_transport_layer.cpp","line":1031}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-03T14:01:59.805-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

I also tried to delete the /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock file. No luck.
My mongod.conf file contains this:
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
  ipv6: true

I see that this issue has been reported several times over a number of years, but I have yet to find a solution in the posts I've read.
:: EDIT ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
After running ls -l /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb I see that everything in the folder looks like is owned by admin. I am aware that this is likely because I have run sudo brew start mongodb-community@8.0 before. This also includes WiredTiger.turtle which has its permissions denied.
However, when I try to run sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/* then I get this error:
chown: mongodb: illegal group name

I'm not sure what group I'm supposed to switch it to, but I suspect that resolving this permissions issue could fix the whole thing...

{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"} simple permissions issue?

@Joe that was my first thought. I just found additional permission denied errors for WiredTiger

Try bindIp: localhost - it's the same. I saw many problems when users tried to bind multiple IP's. For me it looks like the mongodb is already running and you try to start it a second time. Check your running processes and go up in your mongodb log file for other errors.

When I run launchctl list | grep mongo I get the following:
20253 0 application.com.mongodb.compass.146253055.146253060
